# On the Internet, nobody knows you're a dog

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I would like to know whether the adage above could be translated into Latin to make it sound more profound. The user [Sam K](https://latin.stackexchange.com/users/136/sam-k) has suggested the following translation:

> In interneto, nemo scit te canem esse.

[Joonas Ilmavirta](https://latin.stackexchange.com/users/79/joonas-ilmavirta) would prefer the calque *interrete* to *interneto*. Another option would be *internexus*.

Can you think of a way to improve it? It doesn't have to be verbatim.

My attempt follows. I used [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/potes) and a [large collection of latin quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_phrases_(full)) to assemble it, but my knowledge of latin grammar is still nil.  Do you reckon it is adequate?

> In internexus potes esse canis.

Comment: *"incognito"* ?

Comment: *'potes'* means you have the technique to transform into a dog. *'licet'* lets you do so.

Comment: Some comments: 1) Your translation would mean _you can be a dog on the internet_, which is not quite the meaning of the original English wording, 2) I think _Interrete_ is generally agreed to be the most accepted neologism to mean _the Internet_ (although there are people with good reasons to disagree with its form), 3) That said, I would go with Joonas variant of Sam's translation

Comment: A few years ago the expression "tela totius terrae" was in vogue, conveniently shortened to "ttt" to represent "www".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For someone who has "nil" knowledge of Latin grammar, I'm really impressed with your attempt: there's only one grammatical error and the meaning is fairly clear.

First, a grammar correction: *internexus* is presumably a neologism derived from [*nexus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dnexus2), which is the 4th declension. You will thus want to use the ablative singular form:

> In internex**u** potes esse canis.

Literally, this translates as: "On the internet, you can be a dog." As @Rafael pointed out in his comment, this "can" refers to *ability*, not *permission* as can be the case in English. As it stands this is a reasonable attempt at translation, though I tend to think that the joke gets obscured ("you can be a dog...*even though everyone thinks you're a human*").

@SamK's translation is literal but perfectly good. I would just amend to the more commonly understood calque *interrete*:

> In interrete, nemo scit te canem esse.

My proposed translation would rework this a little bit to a more idiomatic phrasing:

> In interrete, canis et homo non distant.
>
> On the internet, a dog and a man do not differ. (lit. "are not distant")

or

> **In interrete, canis ab homine haud differt.**
>
> On the internet, a dog is not different from a man.

or slightly more elliptical:

> **In interrete, canis non cognoscitur.**
>
> On the internet, a dog is not recognized.

I like the two last (bolded) suggestions best.

Comment: I thought of proposing *canis non cognosceris* (being a dog, you would not be recognized) but it struck me as a little off. Thoughts?

Comment: *Canis non cognosceris* sounds fine to me. *Canis non cognoscitur* can also be read as "no one looks what a dog looks like". I would prefer the original ACI structure or *nemo te canem scit/cognoscit* if that's grammatical. (+1 of course)

Comment: I love the last one. I'd also offer *In interrete canis ab homine non internoscitur* or *canis et homo non internoscuntur*.

Comment: One of the issues with your suggestions is that element of surprise in the original is missing. It's the unexpected punchline to a straight-faced joke. I think normal idioms wouldn't work, as they seem too much like a proverb, losing the humor in translation—as translation is wont to do!

Answer (score 6):

I think all Brian's suggestions are wonderful. I'd just add one more:

> **In interrete, canis ab homine non discernitur.**
>
> On the internet, a dog isn't told apart from a man./On the internet, you can't tell a dog from a man.